# What is the correct procedure on scaling and then evaluating performance measures in a regression problem?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, svm, data-science

My data consists only of continuous variables, the independent variables (X) is a number unit, and dependent varaible (Y) is time taken (in minutes).

I'm running SVR model currently among other regression models. But it takes a lot of time to compute on my pc. So I'm looking to scale and then evaluate the model.

What is the full procedure to scale and evaluate? 
1. Do I scale X and Y variables or just X or just Y. 
2. When doing cross-validation, do I scale just training set or test set too? 
3. When evaluating, do I unscale and then calculate performance measures or do I leave it scaled and calculate.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Himanshu.  A perfectly reasonable question, but not one which is really within Stack Overflow's [scope](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  Try https://datascience.stackexchange.com/.